# break a data.frame in groups based on a value using dplyr R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a big data.frame (200000) and I need to add a column for grouping, and the groups are separated by a row with a particular value e.g.

```
  s<-"A B C
  1 2 1
  2 22 3
  0 0 -1
  2 12 2
  0 0 -1
  20 2 5
  1 3 1
  0 2 2"
  d<-read.delim(textConnection(s),sep=" ",header=T)
```

the C==-1 is the break point for each group, what I need as a result are 3 groups:

```
  require(dplyr)
```

here I find the rows that separate groups

```
  mutate(d,rn=row_number()) %>% filter(C==-1)
```

and then I can build the data.frame I need

```
  bind_rows(slice(d, 1:2) %>% mutate(grp=1),slice(d,4) %>%mutate(grp=2), slice(d,6:n()) %>% mutate(grp=3))
```

How can I make it without hard coding the breaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
d %>% mutate(grp = cumsum(C == -1) + 1) %>% filter(C != -1)
```

`cumsum(C == -1)` will give you a group column and all what's left is filter.

Comment: Yep, very nice. In base R, the equivalent is: `transform(d, group=cumsum(C==-1) + 1)[d$C != -1,]`